# Invalid login and password in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Upgrade magento 1.9.x to 2.0.x with migration data tool.
Actual result

When I try to login with any customer email and password I got "Invalid login and password.", but in the old store, the same customers working perfectly.

when i create new user and New customer are login perfectly.

I have also change
key Different.
vi magento1/app/etc/local.xml
vi magento2/app/etc/env.php

I have done all clear cache and re index by command line
Please help me this is very difficulty issue for me

Comment: Hello,

I got another solution and very quick and easy

Just Empty the table (TRUNCATE) " customer_entity_varchar "

100% sure login old customer in New magento 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here. You have to pass a form key . this is new feature in 2.0 ver. Please see that link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55477/login-problems-after-update-to-magento-1-9

Comment: Thanks to reply but i have already add this <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

After migration M1 to M2
old customer login error resole
Please update this query in database

**UPDATE customer_entity_varchar,customer_entity SET customer_entity_varchar.value = customer_entity.password_hash WHERE customer_entity_varchar.entity_id = customer_entity.entity_id and customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id='12'**

attribute_id means password type values id in customer_entity_varchar table see below screenshot

main problem old password value and new password values not match in magneto2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpiqB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgK0g.png)

Comment: Hello,

I got another solution and very quick and easy

Just Empty the table (TRUNCATE) " customer_entity_varchar "

100% sure login old customer in New magento 2

Thanks